# How to migrate a legacy Access 2007 ADP to Access 2016

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, migration, data-conversion, adp

I have been charged with a task to see what it takes to get an old Access 2007 .ADP file to work with Access 2016.

The most important part, I think, is that the project is basically a front end to a MS SQL database backend. This seems to be a challenge in newer versions of Access?

I have not been able to find an exhaustive guide online to my exact problem. What do I need to do? Am I understanding it correctly - Access no longer supports an SQL server as backend? What should I do then?

Thoughts?

With regards

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Access 2013, projects (.adp) are no longer supported.

Create a new Access 2013/2016 database (.mdb or .accdb), link to the ODBC tables in SQL you want to use, then import all the forms, reports & modules into the new database. Probably you'll want to rename all the linked tables to remove the "dbo_" prefix from them.